# Как изменить цвет иконки SVG с помощью CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

На странице есть иконки в формате `SVG`. Сами иконки нарисованы в черном цвете.
Как с помощью `CSS` покрасить их их в красный цвет?

```
<img src='home.svg'>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите тут: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/fill/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если SVG иконка добавлена отдельным файлом с помощью тега `<img>`, то это тоже самое, как добавить растровое изображение,  к которому невозможно применить изменение цвета с помощью CSS правил. Возможно только поменять цвет `background`.

**Но есть способ сделать изменение цвета иконки с помощью фильтров `CSS` или `SVG`**

Допустим добавлена иконка ключа с помощью `<img>`:

```css
img 
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg">
```

С помощью различных css фильтров меняем цвет иконок:

```css
.container {
display:inline-block;
width:25%;
height:25%;
padding:1.5em;
background: rgb(123,215,193);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(123,215,193,1) 4%, rgba(225,233,148,1) 97%);
}
.key {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
 
   }
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.invert {
  
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="key" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
  <img class="key grey-out" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
   <img class="key hue-rotate" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
    <img class="key invert" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg">
</div>
```

**Пример, если svg файл добавлен с помощью background-image:**

```css
.key {
  background-image: url("https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f506.svg");
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0 0.15em 0 0.3em;
  vertical-align: -0.3em;
  background-size: 3em 3em; 
 }
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.invert {
   -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="key"></span>
  <span class="key grey-out"></span>
  <span class="key hue-rotate"></span>
  <span class="key invert"></span>
</div>
```

**Вариант с изменением цвета при наведении**

```css
.container {
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex; 
width:35%;
height:35%;
}
.key {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
   padding: 1em;
   transition:  0.8s;
   }
:hover.key{
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(320deg);
     filter: hue-rotate(320deg);
   }
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);

  
}
.invert {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="key" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
  <img class="key grey-out" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
   <img class="key hue-rotate" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
    <img class="key invert" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Фильтры переставь - сначала `-webkit`, потом нормальный.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ зачем? Это ничего не меняет.

Comment: Последним надо ставить свойство из спецификации, чтобы косяки префиксной реализации не перекрывали стандартное поведение.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ ну хорошо, уговорил :-)

Answer (score 5):

В данном контексте, когда svg у вас лежит отдельно в виде файла, через CSS ничего сделать нельзя. Нужно вставить svg в html текстом, тогда появится возможность использовать в css свойство `fill` к тегу svg и его вложенным тегам.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте свойство `fill`:

```css
#star {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>С заливкой</h3>
<svg aria-hidden="true" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 18 18" id = "star">
  <path d="M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z">   
    </path>
</svg>
<h3>Без заливки</h3>
<svg aria-hidden="true" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
    <path d="M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z">
    </path>
</svg>
```

Но загружать не через img, а через тег svg.

Comment: твоя разметка не соответствует разметке в вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy Это для примера.

Comment: Примера, который никак не помогает автору вопроса?:)