# Почему не работает заливка с svg?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь залить иконку красным цветом, но не получается, (пробовал и в тег path засовывать и без него, менял img на svg, всё без толку) вот код:

```
<div class="bpt-ico bpt-heart"><img class="ico" src="image/main/heart.svg"></div>
```

Стили CSS:

```
.bpt-ico{
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: .5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bpt-ico:hover{
    background-color: #EF3124 !important;
}

.bpt-ico:hover svg path{
    fill: white !important;
}
```

Сразу говорю, код не мой, пытаюсь менять существующий. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: «менял img на svg» — покажите этот вариант

Comment: Вероятно потому что в самом svg есть заливка.

Comment: Если поставлю svg, то иконка вообще пропадает
`<div class="bpt-ico bpt-heart"><svg class="ico" src="image/main/heart.svg"></div>`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928868/ тут уже давали ответ на такой же вопрос